# Magento override template only once

Tags: magento, caching, magento2

I have magento Magento  2.4.3

I create a module to ovveride the Logo.
It works.

After first enable i see my new logo in

```
app\code\MyVendor\MyModule\view\frontend\templates\html\header\logo.phtml
```

I edited again the template but i can't see my new edits.

I tried all this command:

```
rm -rf generated
rm -rf var/cache
rm -rf var/generation

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

But i see always my first code.
Why?
Where magento have this file files persisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.
It was php cache.
I use

```
opcache_reset()
```

Before clean Magento Cache